# datatables rowcallback and colvis and statesave

Tags: datatables

I am using datatables with statesave, colvis button to select the visibility of columns and rowcallback to put some colors on my data.

Here is my code:

```
activitiesTable = $('#activitiesTable').DataTable({
      scrollX: true,
      serverSide: true,
      processing: true,
      stateSave: true,
...
buttons: [
        {
          extend: "colvis",
          className: "btn-sm",
          columns: [ 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32 ]
        },
...
rowCallback: function(row, data, index){
        if(data.jan_com<= 0){
          $(row).find('td:eq(4)').addClass('zero');
        }
        else if(data.jan_otl> 0){
          $(row).find('td:eq(4)').addClass('otl');
        }
        else {
          $(row).find('td:eq(4)').addClass('forecast');
        }
        if(data.feb_com<= 0){
          $(row).find('td:eq(5)').addClass('zero');
        }
        else if(data.feb_otl> 0){
          $(row).find('td:eq(5)').addClass('otl');
        }
        else {
          $(row).find('td:eq(5)').addClass('forecast');
        }
...
```

So as you can see, I change the color of my data with class zero, forecast or otl.

The problem is that because it changes the columns that appear, the next time I reload, the colors are applied to the wrong column because column 4 is not anymore the column jan_com.

Is there a way to find the td corresponding to the column jan_com instead of asking td:eq(4)?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try the className option in columnDefs?  If you add a special class, the class should move with the column

Comment: very clever, thanks it solved my problem...